# Make a hole in a face created by the solidify modifier

Tags: mesh

[image]I have half a cube that has a solidify modifier. I want to make a hole in 1 of the faces created by the modifier, but it doesn't work with boolean.

How can I make a hole in a solidified face?

Comment: hello, it should work, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: what do you mean with "half a cube"? can u provide screenshots?

Comment: you can use built-in adon called Bool Tool, and than select both objects and press ctrl+Numpad-

Comment: cheatPKL, That works very well, but what are the lines that I see afterwards and how do I get them away

Comment: Those lines are the bounding box of the boolean object. If you hide the boolean object in the outliner they will disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work.  Here's a cube that I cut in half and applied a solidify modifier to:

[image: Half a cube with a solidify modifier]

Here's a cylinder positioned to cut the top and bottom faces generated by solidify

[image: Half cube plus cylinder]

Here's what it looks like with the cylinder hidden and a Boolean added to the cube:

[image: Boolean modifier in place; cylinder hidden]

Here's the modifier stack for the half cube:

[image: modifier stack with solidify and Boolean]

Some things you need to be aware of

- The solidify has to come before the Boolean on the modifier stack
- You have to use a cylinder to cut the hole, not a circle; but a smaller cylinder would cut just one face
- You won't see the modifier in edit mode, unless you enable the Edit mode visibility
- The cylinder won't disappear. You either have to hide it, as I did, or set it's Viewport visibility appropriately to something like wire or bounds.

Comment: Thanks, that works, it was that I had the boolean after the solidify.